# Advice using the theano implementation of Conv3D

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, theano, convolution

I am trying to run a 3D convolutional neural network using theano, however I am not completely sure of the usage of the function `theano.tensor.nnet.Conv3d`.

I am used to using lasagne, however due to not having access to a GPU at this time I am unable to use the `lasagne.layers.dnn.Conv3DDNNLayer`function.

Is anyone able to advise me in terms of inputs and outputs what I need to do to be able to use the theano function? I have data in the form N x 9 x 9 x 9 with 1 channel, and have initialised the theano tensors. I have also created an input layer with lasagne like so:

```
input = lasagne.layers.InputLayer((None, 1, 9, 9, 9), input_var=input_var)
```

Any advice is very welcome! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no 3D conv support in Lasagne other than cuDNN.
However I have fork of lasagne that implements it:
https://github.com/gyglim/Lasagne (Conv3DLayer)

Its outputs are identical with the ones from Conv3DDNNLayer.

There is also discussion about adding it to the core lasagne (see https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/issues/27), but it hasn't happend yet.

Hope this helps.

Cheers,
Michael

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get access to a cuda GPU so have been able to run the lasagne version on there! I think it would have been far too slow without it anyway :)